# jquery intervals in deferred objects

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval, jquery-deferred, clearinterval

I have use jQuery deferred object in the past with no problems and I understand how they work.

I now have come across a new situation where I need to use them again.

I have a few similar functions like this which I add to a deferred array. These function use ajax to get a value every 5 seconds until a counter reaches 0

```
deferreds.push(
    getQueueCount()
);

function getQueueCount()
{
    var counter = 1,
        intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            if(counter > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'path/to/script',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        'queuename': 'myqueue',
                        'total' : 10
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#progress').width(response.width + "%").find('span').text(response.width + '%');
                        counter = response.size;
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                intervalId = null;
                counter = 1;

                return intervalId;
            }

        }, 5000);
}
```

However when i run the following code, the button is enabled

```
$.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function() {
    $('#btn-sync').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

My question is how can I prevent the button from enabling until my function is complete?  I need the function to be classed as complete when the counter in each function reaches 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
function getQueueCount()
{
    var dfrQueue = new $.Deferred(),
        counter = 1,
        intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            if(counter > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'path/to/script',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        'queuename': 'myqueue',
                        'total' : 10
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#progress').width(response.width + "%").find('span').text(response.width + '%');
                        counter = response.size;
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                dfrQueue.resolve('queue');
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                counter = 1;
            }

        }, 5000);

     console.log('initialize test for queue');
     return dfrQueue.promise();
}

$.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function(arg) {
    // all operations has completed and console out the argument provided by the last operation that completed.
    console.log('all process succeeded: ' + arg);
});
```